# Create range in base of ratio

Tags: arithmetic, scoring-algorithm

I have a big problem to calculate votes with my excel documents. I have some field for a project: - minimum estimate in hours (before I start a project I tell how many hours I think to do for this project) - maximum estimate in hours(before I start a project I tell how many hours maximum I think to do for this project) - hours total (after the complete project I assign the total hours)

In base of this value I wanna create a range start from 1 to 10 where 10 is the minimum value ( minimum estimate in hours) and 6 is the sufficient value ( maximum estimate in hours) and if I take more hours than my maximum votes is negative progressively

Example:

Minimun hours: 10 Maximum hours: 20 Total effective hours: 20 Votes-----> 6

Minimun hours: 10 Maximum hours: 20 Total effective hours: 10 Votes-----> 10

Minimun hours: 10 Maximum hours: 20 Total effective hours: 30 Votes-----> 4(estimate value)

How can I do this range in math? COnsider that I have an excel document to do it.

Thanks

Comment: [This was also posted to mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28951). Please note that [crossposting between SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) - try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site. If you insist on posting in many sites, at least provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to find out that you'd already gotten the solution elsewhere.

Comment: Ok I have deleted the post in the other site and now? @ZevChonoles How can I have help for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m$ denote the minimum estimate, $M$ the maximum estimate, $T$ the total, $V$ the votes.  One approach is $$v=10-\frac{4(T-m)}{M-m}$$

There are two flaws here; one, the result might not be an integer and two, the result might be negative.  To fix these, try instead $$v=\mathsf{MAX}\left(1,\;\mathsf{ROUND}\left(10-\frac{4(T-m)}{M-m}\right)\right)$$

Comment: man this works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.